# Ubuntu 19.10 download. Is there a problem?

Tags: windows-10, downloads, 19.10

I run 18.04 on my boat computer and wanted to try 19.10 on my desktop, but three download attempts have all failed after downloading 2.0 GB out of 2.3 GB.

Is this a problem with the download or with my computer which is currently running Windows 10 Professional?

Comment: There is no way for us to know what the problem is. I'd use a bittorrent client in such a case.

Comment: I have downloaded 19.10 several times with no problems.

Comment: Try a different mirror `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors` if you do not succeed with the automatically chosen one.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with you filesystem. Where do you try to store the file?

Answer (score 3):

The computer saves files by default in the Downloads folder.  That is not the problem because I have downloaded and saved much bigger files.  I tried a different mirror, with the same result, but then I installed qBittorrent and used it and that downloaded the whole thing, solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)